# Insert Template by Placeholder

Tags: java, freemarker

I'd like to load different Freemarker templates into an existing text depending on the placeholders in there.

So for example I have a Text like this:
This is a Text containing the ${placeholderForATemplate} but also it may contains another template ${placeholderForAnotherTemplate}.

This templates can also include some placeholders.

Now depending on if a Placeholder exists or not I'd like to load the matching template.

Is there a way to do something like that with freemarker?

Comment: Yup, that's what these templating engines like Freemarker or Velocity works :-) Take a look on the [Getting started guide](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_basics.html).

Comment: Hey, I think u got me wrong, I don't want the default "I have a template with some placeholders to replace" but a StringWriter containing a text which contains placeholders which should be replaced by templates which again contains placeholders which should be replaced by some other data.

Comment: Ahh, I just found the #include, I think what I want can be done with this one :)
http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html